# ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected using case statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to run this query, but I am getting the following error : *ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected*.

```
select  case when  trunc( MGM.period_start_time, 'mi' ) < (trunc( MGM.period_start_time, 'hh' ) +numToDSInterval( 15, 'minute' )) 
        then trunc( MGM.period_start_time, 'hh' )
        when  trunc( MGM.period_start_time, 'mi' ) < (trunc( MGM.period_start_time, 'hh' ) +numToDSInterval( 30, 'minute' )) 
        then (trunc( MGM.period_start_time, 'hh' ) +numToDSInterval( 15, 'minute' ))
        when  trunc( MGM.period_start_time, 'mi' ) < (trunc( MGM.period_start_time, 'hh' ) +numToDSInterval( 45, 'minute' )) 
        then (trunc( MGM.period_start_time, 'hh' ) +numToDSInterval( 30, 'minute' )) 
        else (trunc( MGM.period_start_time, 'hh' ) +numToDSInterval( 45, 'minute' )) 
        end as trunc(MGM.period_start_time ,'mi') period_start_time, 
        SUM(test_date) OVER (ORDER BY TRUNC(MGM.period_start_time, 'mi') range between interval '0' minute PRECEDING and interval '60' minute following ) sum_total 
from MGM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
end as trunc(MGM.period_start_time ,'mi') period_start_time
```

This should probably be

```
end as period_start_time
```

Comment: that works...thank you